# OpenCV & Flask: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Tags: python, opencv, segmentation-fault

I am currently using Flask and the WebUI module to create a desktop application that uses OpenCV. One problem I am having is every time I try to open the OpenCV camera, it throws an error.

The function that I am calling is:

```
@app.route('/start-camera')
def startCamera():
    global cameraState, video
    while cameraState:
        ret, frame = video.read()
        cv2.imshow('Camera', frame)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The error I get is

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this/get around it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2):

Code 139 means [Segmentation Fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

Please upgrade to at least Python 3.7.5 and tell me if it works.